# Cant update Database - Custom Wordpress

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

Just recently got into working with PHP and MySQL databases, so this may be obvious. Appreciate the help. This is with WordPress. I can't seem to get information from a form to update my DB. Anyone happen to see where I am going to wrong?

Here is truncated form.

```
<form id="addRfis" method="POST" name="front_end_upload">            
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <label>Internal ID<span class="flaticon-questions1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Individual for each user."></span></label>
        <input type="text" name="user_proj_number" value="<?php echo $user->user_proj_number; ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 buttons" style="margin-top:20px">
        <input type="submit" class="button full-width" value="UPDATE">
    </div>
</form>
```

And here is DB Update Code.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

$process = function() {

    $user = ca_get_user(get_current_user_id());
    $role = $user->role;

    global $wpdb, $caemails;

    $data = array(
        'review'    => $_POST['project_review'],
        'rfi_send'  => $_POST['project_allow']          
    );      
    $wpdb->update($wpdb->prefix . 'cadoc_projects', $data, array('id' => $_GET['project']));

    $data = array(
        'user_proj_number'      => $_POST['user_proj_number'],
        'user_prefix'           => $_POST['user_prefix']            
    );
    $where = array (
        'user_id'=> $user->id
    );
    $wpdb->update($wpdb->prefix . 'cadoc_users', $data, $where);        

    return true;
};

$response = $process();
}
```

The portion I am working with right now is the `user_proj_number`. The column is created in the database and when I populate it through phpMyAdmin I can get it to show up in input field but I cant update it. I've confirmed that `$user->id` is returning right number and that `user_id` is correct key, `cadoc_users` is correct table including multi-site prefix.

Comment: no form action specified..

Comment: Adding action =" " didnt help any. this Update code is on same page.

Comment: what does `echo  $wpdb->last_error;` after your last update give you? The rest of the code seems fine, do you have a seperate table called wp_cadoc_users rather than wp_users?

Comment: Thanks for that bit of code. It was actually the attempt to load the other fields that weren't in table yet (i.e. user_prefix) that was causing it not to work. Didn't know that would stop entire process. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually the attempt to upload the other fields that weren't in table yet (i.e. user_prefix) that was causing it not to work. I removed those from the array to send and started working.